# Why do I get a #N/A error on some rows and others works fine

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I have this formula expanding to the entire column

```
=IF(F2=LOOKUP(F2,NR_infra!A:A),1,0)
```

However I am getting a N/A in return up to row 3211. From 3212 up to the last row it works fine.

Any ideas?

I just want to add that NR_infra Sheet was imported from a CSV.

[image: Capture]

Comment: from the office help: "If lookup_value is smaller than the smallest value in lookup_vector, LOOKUP returns the #N/A error value." This might be the problem.

Comment: If I apply the same formula but in the same sheet and it works fine

Answer (score 2):

LOOKUP doesn't appear to be the best function for this. If you receive an #N/A error, that will be the result from the formula. VLOOKUP would be better with error control.

```
=IF(F2=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2, NR_infra!A:A, 1, FALSE), ""), 1, 0)
'alternate
=--isnumber(match(F2, NR_infra!A:A, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks. It still makes no sense. The columns in NR_infra are all alike yet for some reason I've got 3 and not 2 possible values except 0 and 1